# Get list of videos uploaded before and after certain video

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-apis-explorer

Youtube use to have a feature where you could click a more videos button while watching any video, and see a snapshot of the uploads playlist with videos uploaded before and after the one you are currently watching.

I am trying to get a list like that with the v3 data API and it seems there is no way. There use to be a way to dictate an index when using the playlistItems call, but now there isn't.

If you go to a channels upload playlist and click play all, you can see a list of videos surrounding the one you are watching, so it seems this functionality is possible, but I don't know how they are doing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you referring to [snippet.position](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems)?

Comment: @noogui Yes, but how would you actually utilize it? With youtube's V2 data api, you could input a startingPosition parameter with a playlistItems.list call, but that seems to be gone now.

If it is impossible to start the call at an index, would I just have to keep making api calls with the next page token until I got to the spot I needed?

Comment: @noogui any ideas?